# Php smtp error godaddy

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, gmail

Estoy tratando de enviar un formulario en PHP para enviarlo a través del servidor de Godaddy, pero cuando lo envío me sale el error

```
<?php
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$compania = $_POST['compania'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$pais = $_POST['pais'];
$videoconferencia = $_POST['videoconferencia'];




if ($nombre==''||
$email==''){

echo "<script>alert('Los campos marcados con * son obligatorios');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

}else{


    require("includes/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From     = ("usuario@hosting.com"); //Correo creado en el hosting
    //$mail->FromName = $nombre; 
    $mail->AddAddress("usuario@gmail.com"); //Correo de gmail donde se quiere que llegue el correo
// Dirección a la que llegaran los mensajes.

// Aquí van los datos que apareceran en el correo que reciba

    //$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);     
    $mail->Subject  =  "";
    $mail->Body     =  '<html><body><br />'.
'<h2><font face="times new roman" color="#000000"><span><font face="times new roman" color="#00769f">Datos del cliente</h2></font>'.
    "<table style='border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px; border-color:#A5D7DF;'><tr><td><strong>Pais</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($nombre) . "</td><br/></tr>".

    "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($email) . "</td></tr>".

     "<tr><td><strong>Compañia:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($compania ) . "</td></tr>".

      "<tr><td><strong>Telefono:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($telefono) . "</td></tr>".

       "<tr><td><strong>Estado / Pais:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($pais) . "</td></tr>".


       "<tr><td><strong>Localidad/El cliente va a usar Videoconferencia proximamente:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($videoconferencia) . "</td></tr>".




        '<tr><td></td></tr></table>'.

    "<br />";

// Datos del servidor SMTP

   // Datos del servidor SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
$mail->Username = "usuario@hosting.com"; //Correo creado en el hosting
$mail->Password = "*******"; //Password
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Port = 25;

    if ($mail->Send())
    echo "<script>alert('Formulario Enviado');location.href ='';</script>";
    else
    echo "<script>alert('Error al enviar el formulario');location.href ='javascript:history.back()';</script>";

}
?>
```

Comment: Aver @Alejandro_Montes lo que tu quieres es crear un formulario para enviar datos al Gmail?

Comment: Hola Gilberto si es lo que estoy intentando sin éxito :(.

Comment: Ya he encontrado el problema. El servidor me devuelve un enlace con un token que hay que validar para que te permita enviar correos de esa manera. Voy a usar el enlace y ver si con una vez ya es suficiente.

Comment: La cosa pinta mal, he validado el token, he habilitado aplicaciones menos seguras, he desactivado el captcha y me sigue pidiendo el token en cada envío. Seguiré probando y te contaré, no sé si está relacionado con ser una cuenta nueva, probaré con la clave de aplicación al usar segundo factor.

Comment: Ya está solucionado, te redacto la respuesta.

Comment: ¿Pudiste comprobar la respuesta que te ofrecí?

Answer (score 1):

**Tercera edición**

Tras consultar la documentación de Goddady la configuración del servidor saliente debe ser la siguiente:

- Servidor Linux con [cPanel](https://es.godaddy.com/help/configuring-the-smtp-relay-server-on-your-linux-server-using-cpanel-5378), [Simple Control Panel](https://es.godaddy.com/help/configuring-the-smtp-relay-server-on-your-linux-server-using-simple-control-panel-5379) o [Plesk](https://es.godaddy.com/help/configuring-your-smtp-relay-server-on-your-linux-server-using-parallels-plesk-panel-5377): `localhost`
- En cualquier otro caso (incluso para configurar algunos de los anteriores) hay que hacer una búsqueda manual en el [panel de control de Goddady](https://es.godaddy.com/help/find-your-email-relay-server-122).

Por lo que el código quedaría:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
/* No es necesario realizar autenticación para el host local */
/*$mail->Username = "usuario@hosting.com"; //Correo creado en el hosting
$mail->Password = "*******"; //Password*/
```

Tienes un límite de [500 envíos por hora](https://es.godaddy.com/help/outgoing-email-smtp-limit-16232) y [1000 envíos al día](https://es.godaddy.com/help/find-your-email-relay-server-122).

**Segunda edición**

Parece que con cuentas nuevas, sin segundo factor de autenticación o sin validar el número de teléfono no pueden enviar correos mediante SMTP. A mi correo llegó un correo indicándome que había sido bloqueada una aplicación insegura, pero no había ningún enlace para permitir su acceso ni nada por el estilo.

Activando la depuración (con `$mail->SMTPDebug = true;`) se puede ver que el servidor responde con:

```
534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=aaaaaaaa
534-5.7.14 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
534-5.7.14 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
534-5.7.14 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
534-5.7.14 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 xxxxxxxxxxxx.99 - gsmtp
```

Seguí las instrucciones que aparecían en el [centro de ayuda de gmail (I can't sign in to my email client)](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=1-636317685485198806-4144274324&rd=2#cantsignin).

Tras [dar acceso a las aplicaciones menos seguras](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) el problema persistía, por lo que procedí a utilizar [el último método](https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) sin éxito.

Finalmente me decidí a usar una de mis cuentas con segundo factor de autenticación y [generé una contraseña de aplicación](https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords).

Con mi dirección de correo electrónico como usuario y esa contraseña de aplicación generada (se genera aleatoriamente y no puedes cambiarla, sólo copiarla en el portapapeles y pegarla en tu código) pude enviar un correo de manera inmediata.

Así que mi recomendación es que finalices las comprobaciones de seguridad y de identidad (si no lo has hecho) y si sigues sin poder enviar correos activar el segundo factor de autenticación y generar una contraseña de aplicación.

**Respuesta original**

Tienes un error con el nombre de la instancia de `PHPMailer` aquí:

```
$mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Servidor de Salida.
```

Debería ser:

```
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465';  // Servidor de Salida.
```

En la siguiente página tienes un ejemplo de cómo conectarte a Gmail:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Por lo que podrías cambiar tu código a éste:

```
// Datos del servidor SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Servidor de Salida.
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = "usuario@gmail.com";  // Correo Electrónico
$mail->Password = ""; // Contraseña
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
```

Comment: Lo acabo de colocar pero me da el mismo error

Comment: ¿Has usado tus credenciales correctas? ¿podrías editar tu pregunta con los cambios que has hecho para que pruebe con las mías?

Comment: Oscar ya actualice el codigo y asi queda pero me da el mismo error.

Comment: Voy a mirar, mientras dime qué versión de PHP y de PHPMailer estás usando, mis cuentas de gmail tienen segundo factor de autenticación, así que tendré que crear una tercera para poder probar tu código.

Comment: Oscar uso https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: ¿Leíste mi última edición? ¿podrías agregar la línea de depuración que te indico y comprobar que es el mismo problema que sufres?

Comment: Oscar ya cambie el codigo he hice la autenticacion de 2 pasos  y nada

Comment: Oscar intente con la configuracion smtp de mi servidor     // Datos del servidor SMTP
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'a2plcpnl0885.prod.iad2.secureserver.net';  // Servidor de Salida.
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Username = "";  // Correo Electrónico
$mail->Password = ""; // Contraseña
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";  Me funciono pero solo puedo enviar correos a mi domino si agrego enviar a gmail no me deja

Comment: ¿Activaste la depuración para ver el mensaje con el que te respondía el servidor?

Comment: Me da este error 2017-06-01 04:51:53 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2017-06-01 04:51:53 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Si te da conexión rechazada y el host y puerto están correctos entonces deberías contactar con tu proveedor de alojamiento. Es probable que tengan filtrado el tráfico SMTP al exterior y debas solicitar que lo abran.

Comment: Llame al servidor de godaddy y me dijeron que tenia que usar el SMTP relay-hosting.secureserver.net pero no se como realizar el codigo en php

Comment: Sólo necesitas cambiar tu host a ese y listo, has preguntado el puerto y si necesitas autenticación?

Comment: Me dicen que no pero no se que plantilla usar que me funcione porque cambie el servidor y me da el mismo error

Comment: Es que probablemente sea el puerto 25.. prueba con ese puerto y me dices

Comment: Ya cambie el puerto y subi el nuevo codigo y nada

Comment: Tendrás que llamar a soporte y preguntar los parámetros exactos: servidor, puerto, y autenticación (en caso de necesitarlo si no es open relay) y seguridad (ssl, starttls, etc). Con esos datos te puedo decir cómo configurarlos en phpmailer.

Comment: Veo que has editado tu pregunta (si no me dejas un mensaje la página no me avisa). En cuanto tenga un hueco lo miro (no soy cliente de goddady, pero seguro que tienen alguna página con los datos de configuración).

Comment: Hola @AlejandroMontes. Acabo de estar mirando por la página de soporte y resulta que dependiendo de tu contrato el servidor de salida cambia. En el caso de servidores con cPanel, por ejemplo, debe activarse el smarthost y usar `localhost` como servidor de salida: https://es.godaddy.com/help/configuring-the-smtp-relay-server-on-your-linux-server-using-cpanel-5378